# UIViewController xib file containing a collectionview with a custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xib

I have a xib file containing an `UIViewController` called `FullScreenGalleryVC`. It contains a `UICollectionView` that contains a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, which identifier is `fullscreen_cell`.

When I want to create a new `FullScreenGalleryVC`, I call `FullscreenGalleryVC.display(from: self)`.

Here's the func:

```
class func display(from sourcevc:UIViewController){
    let vc=UINib(nibName: "FullscreenGalleryVC", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! FullscreenGalleryVC
    sourcevc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I get this error:

> could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier fullscreen_cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

---

It works fine if I put the custom cell in another xib file and call `register(nibClass, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)`.

It works fine if I don't put this `FullScreenGalleryVC` class in a separate xib file (and keep it in my main storyboard).

---

But **I use this class from both the app and an action extension** so that's why I'd like to use a common file instead of duplicating everything. **Is there a way to do that or do I imperatively have to put the custom cell in a different xib file to make it work?**

[image]

Comment: Did you implement `override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }` and 
    
    `required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }`  `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourXib", owner: self, options: nil)` ?

Comment: @canister_exister no, why do I need it?

Comment: Because you create xib. Check some tutorials, like: https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-swift-creating-a-custom-view-with-xib-ace878cd41c5 and this: https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Not yet. I checked your links but they are not helping. I know how to create a custom view or cell from a xib file but this case is specific. I think I either need to make a separate xib for the cell or create another storyboard like @Bappaditya suggested. Maybe it's not possible this way.

Comment: if you remove you cell from table view is it gonna work?

Comment: @canister_exister yes, like I said "It works fine if I put the custom cell in another xib file".

Answer (score 1):

If you a xib file for `FullScreenGalleryVC` controller then you should use `register(nibClass, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)` to tell the collection view how to create a new cell of the given type.

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "FullScreenGalleryCell", bundle: .main) 
collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "fullscreen_cell")
```

If you use a `storyboard`, then it's already known to the collection view with the specified `cellId`.

In my opinion, you can use a `storyboard` for `FullScreenGalleryVC` and reuse the same for other classes.

Present a viewController from a specific `storyboard` like,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardId")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: image 1][image: image 2]

Comment: If I use `let nibCell=UINib(nibName: "FullScreenGalleryCell", bundle: nil)` and `register(nibCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "fullscreen_cell")` I get `Could not load NIB in bundle`. If I use the xib file name instead: `let nibCell=UINib(nibName: "FullscreenGalleryVC", bundle: nil)` and  `register(nibCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "fullscreen_cell")` I get `invalid nib registered for identifier (fullscreen_cell)`.

Comment: Try this, `let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "FullScreenGalleryCell", bundle: .main)` `collectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "fullscreen_cell")`

Comment: I get `Could not load NIB in bundle 'NSBundle <.../AppName.app> (loaded)' with name 'FullScreenGalleryCell'`.

Comment: Here's the full error message from the case above: `invalid nib registered for identifier (fullscreen_cell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance`.

Comment: It works with a separate storyboard but I don't know how to make it work with a xib file, maybe it's not meant for this.